# Loading XML layout from server pros and cons?

Tags: android, android-layout

In order to avoid frequent updates is it a good practice/is it possible to load XML layout from the server? So any necessary changes can be done on the backend without having to update the app.

Comment: you can create your layout dynamically using java code but I don't think you can load xml at runtime.

Comment: I think its not possible to load xml at run time. For that I think you use some xml Layout as per requirement and after that use API to set for dynamic data from server,

Comment: If there was something like that it would be really nice but unfortunately I don't think we have such a feature now.

Comment: Your necessary changes are unusable, even you can draw dynamically UI, code that interact with them is missing. Why not creating web apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> When your application is compiled, `aapt` generates the `R` class, which
>   contains `resource IDs` for all the resources in your `res/ directory`.
>   For each type of resource, there is an `R` subclass (for example,
>   `R.drawable` for all `drawable` resources), and for each resource of that
>   type, there is a `static integer` (for example, `R.drawable.icon`). This
>   integer is the `resource ID` that you can use to retrieve your `resource`.

So, `layout` files are `compiled` (`in a binary-like format`) as part of your project. If the `XML` was not part of your project at build time, you won't be able to use it during `run-time`.

> is it a good practice/is it possible to load XML layout from the server?

No because of what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

to do a native vs runtime/remote layout inflation depends on your use case. (so I will not touch on whether it is good practice or not).

as to how to accomplish a runtime layout inflation -> you can use https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus as a replacement for your layoutInflator

from the page it states that

> Instead of writing layouts in XML, in proteus layouts are described in JSON, which can be used to inflate native Android UI at runtime. The JSON layouts can be hosted anywhere (on the device, on servers, etc.).